# why does IE eat my Memory?

Tags: internet-explorer, xml-serialization

why does IE get +3GB of my ram and crashes my computer when i try to open a serialized dataset or datatable with it.
file size = 10MB

Comment: Maybe because your DataSet is too large? How large is it?

Comment: notepad opens the files in 100ms.so the files don't have any problems!!

Comment: How are you accessing said data?

Comment: Short answer: it is a Microsoft product. Long answer: there is a bug.

Comment: Memory tastes nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serialized data set is XML. If you're opening XML files -- particularly large ones -- in IE, not only is the document in RAM, but so is the entire node tree, and Microsoft client-side scripts which provide the syntax highlighting and node collapsing. IE has been (for me) notoriously slow and flaky when opening XML files, so I won't do it anymore.

If you're loading it into an app via DOM loading or script (which would make this programming-related and thus qualify it to get sent back to StackOverflow), you have even more to think about -- including your script's overall performance and memory overhead.

Comment: it is migrated from stackoverflow by other people not me myself.

Comment: @behrooz: I know. I unfortunately don't have close/migrate permissions on this site, otherwise I'd have probably voted to send it back where it belongs.

Comment: Just by the way, it is good policy on this site to flag questions for moderator attention, if you don't have the reputation to close/migrate them back.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Normally I would have done exactly that; however in this case, I do think it's somewhat ambiguous as to which site it truly belongs to, and fear the SO community would again kick it back here.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen IE run amok and run my machines out of RAM when there's some shaky javascript code running.  Doesn't seem to handle the case of bad javascript as well as other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dataset is pretty heavy as it uses alot of xml. I would recommend using JSON. Its faster easier to consume using a browser and has a small footprint